# Trying to return two pointer to two dimensional Array in C

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I'm very new to C and having trouble returned a pointer to a two dimensional array.

The purpose of the code is to go into a folder called rules. From this folder it finds all the file paths for all the files in the rule folder. I want to populate the a two dimensional array with the complete file paths. As of now my code is capable of populating a two dimensional array with the the filepaths (this is done in the listFiles Method). I would like to use this two dimensional array within the main method, to do some further stuff. But I am having issues trying to get it to return, without causing compiling issues.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#ifdef WINDOWS
#include <direct.h>
#define GetCurrentDir _getcwd
#else
#include <unistd.h>
#define GetCurrentDir getcwd
#endif
#include <string.h>

void listFiles(char *path);

int main() {
  // Directory path to list files
  char path[100];
  char buff[FILENAME_MAX];
  GetCurrentDir(buff, FILENAME_MAX);
  // printf("%s\n",buff);
  char toRuleFolder[100] = "/rules";
  strcat(buff, toRuleFolder);
  // printf("%s\n",buff);

  listFiles(buff);

  return 0;
}

void listFiles(char *path) {
  char pathToUse[100];
  struct dirent *dp;

  char *arrayOfArraysOfChars[30][50]; // array to hold     multiple single
                                      // arrays of characters
  DIR *dir = opendir(path);
  printf(" %s\n", path);

  return;

  char *token;
  const char s[2] = "-";
  int counter = 0;
  char pathToSave[100];

  while ((dp = readdir(dir)) != NULL) {

    token = strtok(dp->d_name, "");

    while (token != NULL) {

      if (strcmp(token, ".") != 0) {
        if (strcmp(token, "..") != 0) {

          strcpy(pathToSave, "");
          strcpy(pathToSave, path);
          strcat(pathToSave, "/");
          strcat(pathToSave, token);

          strcpy(arrayOfArraysOfChars[counter], pathToSave);

          counter += 1;
        }
      }

      token = strtok(NULL, s);
    }
  }

  printf("%s\n", "sdasdasdssad");
  printf("%s\n", arrayOfArraysOfChars[0]);
  printf("%s\n", arrayOfArraysOfChars[1]);
  printf("%s\n", arrayOfArraysOfChars[2]);
  printf("%s\n", arrayOfArraysOfChars[3]);

  closedir(dir);
}
```

arrayOfArraysOfChars is populated with the information I need. But I would like to be able to access this array from the main function. How would I do this?

Comment: You have "compile issues". Please be more precise by quoting the errors messages verbatim and in full.

Comment: Please make your code more readable by using fewer empty lines and more consistent indentation.

Comment: Please describe your understanding of what kind of variable this line creates `char *arrayOfArraysOfChars[30][50];`, including the meaning of `30` and of `50`. In contrast please describe `char arrayOfArraysOfChars[30][50];`

Comment: Within your function, please describe your understanding of what happens at/after the fline `return;`.

Comment: @Stargateur: please do not convert code from Allman to 1TBS style.  Both are acceptable.  Inconsistent code you can choose your format; consistent code should stay consistent with the original intent of the OP.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Sorry, I don't have time to lose when a question doesn't show any effort, I only have this site that don't have all format, this style is the closest thing and I can do rapidly, feel free to rollback. This question is readable now, I don't have 10 minutes to indent the code that respect the "original" style, that just losing time on a poor question.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming your compiler is warning you about returning local variables.

```
char *arrayOfArraysOfChars[30][50]
```

The memory used by this variable will be reused for the next stack frame when the function is finished, overwriting it and making it useless.

a) Pass it in as a parameter

b) Make it static (yuk)

c) Dynamically allocate it and return the pointer

Also, consider using a linked list of allocated strings rather than an array as I guess you don't know for sure how many files you're going to find or how long their names are.